# Why does rsync spawn multiple processes for me?

Tags: linux, rsync

I am using the following cron statement to backup from one folder to another folder in the same machine:

```
19 21 * * * root  rsync -ac --delete /source/folder /dest/folder
```

When I use `pstree`, I see the cron forked three processes

```
 ├─cron───cron───rsync───rsync───rsync
```

And `ps`

```
 9972 ?        Ds     1:00 rsync -ac --delete /source/folder /dest/folder
 9973 ?        S      0:29 rsync -ac --delete /source/folder /dest/folder
 9974 ?        S      0:09 rsync -ac --delete /source/folder /dest/folder
```

Why are three processes? Can I limit to only one?

Comment: Why do you care? Is it causing any performance problems?

Comment: Yes, impact my server performance and they use quite some resource

Answer (score 36):

http://rsync.samba.org/how-rsync-works.html

> Rsync is heavily pipelined. This means that it is a set of processes that communicate in a (largely) unidirectional way. Once the file list has been shared the pipeline behaves like this:
>    generator → sender → receiver
>
> The output of the generator is input for the sender and the output of the sender is input for the receiver. Each process runs independently and is delayed only when the pipelines stall or when waiting for disk I/O or CPU resources.

You are running a local rsync (source and destination are local filesystem) so all three processes will run there.
There is nothing you can do, this is by design.

Comment: You cannot limit the number of processes, but you **can** limit the bandwidth used. I assume his machine is flogged by rsync reading and writing to the same disk/block device. Using the '--bwlimit' option may help in this case.